# how to call Async task with in period of time

Tags: android

I want to fetch audio metadata periodically like song name and artist name.
for that i am using media metadata retriever in Async-task.
So problems are

1) In AsyncTask class how can i assign text to Taxt-view.

2) How can i call that Async-task class within a specific time, like 30sec time interval.

3) There are some text which i need to fetch only once in a day. so how can check that when last time data was fetched? and also which is the best method to store that fetch data and use it to Listview?(i mean i need to store that that into database or any hashmap or array list?)

Here is metadata retriver code

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.afragment, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    initfrag();
}

private void initfrag() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    lv1=(ListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.list);

    tv=(TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    tv1=(TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.tv2);
    LongOperation task=new LongOperation();
    task.execute();
}

class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        MediaMetadataRetriever metaRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        String link = "http://xyz-radio-link.ogg";
        metaRetriever.setDataSource(link, new HashMap<String, String>());
        // get mp3 info
        title = metaRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE);
        artist = metaRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST);
        metaRetriever.release();  
        refreshtext();
        return null;
    }      
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {               
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {       
    }
}

public void refreshtext() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(),"fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf");
    tv.setTypeface(tf);
    tv1.setTypeface(tf);
    tv.setText(artist);
    tv1.setText(title);
}
```

Comment: have a service that runs every 30 seconds.

Comment: @Raghunandan can you please tell me in details...like how can i call service in every 30 sec and should i need to use async-task in service ? if yes than again how can i assign text to text view ?...and last question how can i write code which parse json once in day and next time it fetches data from database ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) In AsyncTask class how can i assign text to Taxt-view.

You can't because you are not running on UIThread. IMHO best practice is to return this value to the UIThread using `onPostExecute()`. Another choice is to use `runOnUIThread()` with your own `Runnable` class.

> 2) How can i call that Async-task class within a specific time, like
>   30sec time interval.

You can use [ScheduledExecutorService](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html).

> 3) There are some text which i need to fetch only once in a day. so
>   how can check that when last time data was fetched?

Save the last time into [your DB](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).

> the best method to store that fetch data and use it to Listview?(i
>   mean i need to store that that into database or any hashmap or array
>   list?)

Subclass (extend) [`ArrayAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) for your own needs, then you can directly use it to feed the `ListView`. [Here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#listview_adapterintro)'s an example.

Answer (score 0):

Using a handler, you could create a runnable to run every 30 seconds using [postDelayed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29).